# Flink set Timer and broadcast stream

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Assume I have a config stream which I would like to broadcast to all instances of process operators and I have another non-keyed input stream. I want to have such `ProcessFunction`/`WindowFunction` that can take the config stream and the input stream and can periodically process cached inputs.

I know one solution would be using `KeyedProcessFunction` with a hardcoded key. (Maybe I am wrong) But I am trying to avoid using it because I think `ProcessFunction` would save network transmission since inputs will be evenly distributed to all instances of the process function in different task managers.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with BroadcastStream: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/broadcast_state.html. It works with keyed or non-keyed stream. The example in the documents demonstrates its typical usage: broadcast a pattern(e.g. your config stream) to a keyed stream(can be non-keyed stream, e.g. your input stream).

Comment: But you cannot set a timer in BroadcastProcessFunction..

Comment: @JeromeLi That's true. TimerService is for KeyedStream. One solution is to use a dummy key selector named `NullByteKeySelector` to convert input stream into KeyedStream, then you can use the Timer in `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction`, or you can convert the input stream as a real KeyedStream. The dummy key selector will direct all input to ONE task executor, which is an issue for large data volume.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. With `NullByteKeySelector`, we can convert it into keyed-stream. But it may end up letting all the message goes into the same operator instance. If we end up have parallelism set to 10. It might not perform well...

Comment: My current solution is that adding a random number key to each input messages. The key is randomly generated based on parallelism number. Then use the random number the key to converter the input stream to keyed-stream. Then use `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction` to achieve the goal.

Comment: @JeromeLi Agree. It is also a sound solution.